# kAMD Missing Package Path error in imazing app

Tags: ipa

I tried to install the ipa file through the imazing application.But while installing the file i am seeing the error of **kAMD Missing Package Path error**.I drag and dropped the .ipa file in the imazing app.

Could you please me help to sort out this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5qFH.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Check your signing certificate. An expired cert may prompt this error.